# MVC ActionLink preventDefault() with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link and I want to get it's href attribute and set it to a form.

The form is inside a modal window made using bootstrap 3.

This is my modal window:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmation required</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Id)
                        @Html.Hidden("Decision", "declined")
                        @Html.TextArea("Reason", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Close" />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Decline" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Decline", "ChiefAnswer", null, new { @Id = Model.Id, @Decision = "declined" }, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-default confirmLink", @data_toggle="modal", @data_target="#myModal" });
```

And here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        bgiframe: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 200,
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $(".confirmLink").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var hrefAttribute = $(this).attr("href");
        var form = $('input[type=submit]').closest("form");
        form.attr("href", hrefAttribute);
    });

});
```

The problem is that when I click my ActionLink, the default action is not prevented so it executes that action. The result is not my modal, but the new window result.

In other words, the action link will still go to the page from the href attribute.

Why is this happening? I specified preventDefault function on click event.

Comment: Have you tried an alert or writing to the console to confirm you're hitting that bit of jQuery?

Comment: I tried alerts. It enters that piece of code and executes it.

Comment: OK that's a good start then. Have you tried doing the same with the variables you set up to make sure they get the values you'd expect?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. Same result.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to set an href attribute on your form in your javascript, should this be an action attribute?

Comment: Yes. I see that I posted a wrong version of code here. On my last line Ihave 'form.attr("action", hrefAttribute)'

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work for you:

```
$(".confirmLink").click(function (e) {


        var hrefAttribute = $(this).attr("href");
        var form = $('input[type=submit]').closest("form");
        form.attr("href", hrefAttribute);

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If I put this code, it won't show me the modal window.